# group chat message getting delayed and queued when offline_message_hook is called

Tags: ejabberd

group chat message getting delayed and queued when `offline_message_hook` is called to fire notification. Is there a way to improve this behaviour ?

i created a module to handle APNS notification and called `offline_message_hook` to fire notification.
And the result is the messages distribution in the room are queued and very slowly sending the message when active members sending messages simultaneously, but if i disable the `offline_message_hook` i can see the messages are distributed to members faster significantly.

Is there a way to improve this vehaviour ?

Answer (score 0):

I also handle APNS notification and called offline_message_hook to fire notification. But i `spawn` a new process to handle it. Like this:

> spawn(?MODULE, send_notice, [From, To, NewPacket2, Resource]).

Then the `send_notice` function post the xmpp packet to a rabbitmq server.

Comment: Thank you so much cisiqo.. actually i used to tried this approach previously but the message distribution still not improve .. let me try again with to spawn as the way you advised....